# Why it is showing error when parsing JSON having multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, json

Code:

JSON.parse('{"name":"dibya","company":"wipro}');

Error :

M208:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()
    at :1:6

Comment: That’s not valid JSON, would be the problem.

Comment: first : '{"name":"dibya","company":"wipro}' you forget the "  after wipro 
second that's not the valid json

Answer (score 1):

It throws an error beacuse it is not a valid json. Should be:

```
JSON.parse('{"name":"dibya","company":"wipro"}');
```

You can check if it is valid on https://jsonlint.com/